# where does the Windows Calculator store its settings?

Tags: windows, windows-registry, calculator

Each time I start the Windows Calculator it uses the standard view. It doesn't save the Scientific view, probably because my user account here at work doesn't have write permissions to some part of the registry.

Where exactly is this setting stored?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aaron Margosis explains how to do this in his blog post [Remembering Calculator and Character Map Settings](https://web.archive.org/web/20160204170103/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/aaron_margosis/archive/2005/02/09/370264.aspx).

To quote the relevant parts

> Run regedit.exe as an administrator
>
> Browse to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\IniFileMapping\win.ini
>
> To “fix” Calculator, create a new String value called SciCalc.  Set the data for this string value to
> USR:Software\Microsoft\SciCalc
>
> To “fix” Character Map, create a new String value called MSUCE.  Set the data for this string value to:
> USR:Software\Microsoft\CharMap
>
> Reboot the computer.  (Rebooting is required only if you have used Calculator or CharMap since the previous reboot.)
>
> This will cause the applications’ settings to be written to the registry under HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\SciCalc and HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\CharMap, respectively.  The application settings are now per-user, and admin is no longer required to save settings!

Comment: The page says "Run regedit.exe as an administrator" so that doesn't help me, but thanks for the answer.

Comment: Dead end link, which is why @Mokubai's comment makes so much sense.

Answer (score 5):

Edit `C:\WINDOWS\win.ini` and add

```
[SciCalc]  
layout=0
```

Comment: More like `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Calc\layout = 0` ... besides, if there is a permission problem, then the OP would almost certainly have no permission to write to the Windows directory ...